# bsddb3 cannot read whole file

Tags: python-3.x, bsddb

My code for creating Berkeley DB file:

```py
def create_bdb_object(filename):
    bdb = bsddb3.db.DB()
    bdb.set_flags(bsddb3.db.DB_DUP | bsddb3.db.DB_DUPSORT)
    open_flags = bsddb3.db.DB_CREATE | bsddb3.db.DB_EXCL
    if os.path.exists(filename) and is_create:
        os.remove(filename)
    bdb.open(filename, dbtype=bsddb3.db.DB_BTREE, flags=open_flags)
    return bdb
```

After that, I wrote some pickled data into this file. The file creates without any problems.

**Update#1:**
Code for writing to the file:

```
def write_to_the_file(filename, kv_pair_rdd):
    bdb_filename = f'{filename}.new'
    bdb = create_bdb_object(bdb_filename)

    for url, record in kv_pair_rdd.toLocalIterator():
        bdb.put(url.encode(), pickle.dumps(record, protocol=2))

    bdb.close()
    os.rename(bdb_filename, filename)
```

But when I try to read this file I get not all data from it.
In the file should be 9 records, but after reading I get only 4.

When I do `db_dump -p filename` I get 9 records

Code for reading data from file:

```py
bdb = bsddb3.db.DB()                                                                                                                                                                            
bdb.set_flags(bsddb3.db.DB_DUP | bsddb3.db.DB_DUPSORT)                                   
bdb.open(filename)                                                                 
bdb_cursor = bdb.cursor() 

record = bdb_cursor.first()                                                              
while record:                                  
    print(record[0], pickle.loads(record[1]))                                       
    record = bdb_cursor.next()  

bdb_cursor.close()                                                                        
bdb.close()
```

Could anybody explain to me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: Add please code how you write records to bdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate what the data comes to your file. I used your code and created the following script:

```
import bsddb3
import os
import pickle


def create_bdb_object(filename):
    bdb = bsddb3.db.DB()
    bdb.set_flags(bsddb3.db.DB_DUP | bsddb3.db.DB_DUPSORT)
    open_flags = bsddb3.db.DB_CREATE | bsddb3.db.DB_EXCL
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
    bdb.open(filename, dbtype=bsddb3.db.DB_BTREE, flags=open_flags)
    return bdb


def write_to_the_file(filename, data):
    bdb_filename = f'{filename}.new'
    bdb = create_bdb_object(bdb_filename)

    for url, record in data.items():
        bdb.put(url.encode(), pickle.dumps(record, protocol=2))

    bdb.close()
    os.rename(bdb_filename, filename)


def read_bdb(bdb_filename):
    bdb = bsddb3.db.DB()
    bdb.set_flags(bsddb3.db.DB_DUP | bsddb3.db.DB_DUPSORT)
    bdb.open(bdb_filename)
    bdb_cursor = bdb.cursor()

    record = bdb_cursor.first()
    counter = 1
    while record:
        print('Record num: %s, key: %s, value: %s' % (counter, record[0], pickle.loads(record[1])))
        record = bdb_cursor.next()
        counter += 1

    bdb_cursor.close()
    bdb.close()


def main():
    bdb_filename = '/tmp/bsddb.bdb'
    data = {'www.example1.com': 'lorem ipsum 1',
            'www.example2.com': 'lorem ipsum 2',
            'www.example3.com': 'lorem ipsum 3',
            'www.example4.com': 'lorem ipsum 4',
            'www.example5.com': 'lorem ipsum 5',
            'www.example6.com': 'lorem ipsum 6',
            'www.example7.com': 'lorem ipsum 7',
            'www.example8.com': 'lorem ipsum 8',
            'www.example9.com': 'lorem ipsum 9'}
    write_to_the_file(bdb_filename, data)

    read_bdb(bdb_filename)


main()
```

It works perfectly, can't spot the issue, here's output:

```
Record num: 1, key: b'www.example1.com', value: lorem ipsum 1
Record num: 2, key: b'www.example2.com', value: lorem ipsum 2
Record num: 3, key: b'www.example3.com', value: lorem ipsum 3
Record num: 4, key: b'www.example4.com', value: lorem ipsum 4
Record num: 5, key: b'www.example5.com', value: lorem ipsum 5
Record num: 6, key: b'www.example6.com', value: lorem ipsum 6
Record num: 7, key: b'www.example7.com', value: lorem ipsum 7
Record num: 8, key: b'www.example8.com', value: lorem ipsum 8
Record num: 9, key: b'www.example9.com', value: lorem ipsum 9
```

Maybe, you have some additional code which can modify somehow your data

Comment: Sergius, thanks for your investigation. The main reason was that I have passed and read another file.

Comment: I am getting: `_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.`

Comment: @pbies, need to see your code, version of python and pickle

Comment: @Sergius https://pastebin.com/930F1xzi

Comment: @pbies then maybe you can add the code how do you create that *.,dat file? or some sample file without sensitive information?

Comment: @Sergius it is Bitcoin Core wallet. There are many of them. The idea is to dump these wallets in readable form, any of them. Seems like error is generic.

Comment: @pbies How those wallets were written to db? Have you pickled them? Otherwise it won't work

Comment: @Sergius Bitcoin Core writes these wallets. These are simple key-value databases, it uses bsddb3. What means "to pickle"?

Comment: If they are stored as plain text, without pickling, i.e. "pickle.dump(s)" wasn't executed, then why do you use pickle.loads? just load with bsddb3 lib and read as plain text

Comment: @Sergius binary format of these wallet files would not matter? Thank you for suggestion!